# How to read the height and weight data that we enter in the health app to our custom app

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

How to read the height and weight data values that we enter in the health app to our custom app?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code snippets you have tried yet.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Request HealthKit authorization:**

```
- (void)checkHealthStoreAuthorization
{
    if ([HKHealthStore isHealthDataAvailable]) {
        NSSet *readDataTypes = [self dataTypesToRead];

        if (!self.healthStore) {
            self.healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];
        }

        static NSInteger i = 0;
        for (HKObjectType * quantityType in readDataTypes) {
            if ([self.healthStore authorizationStatusForType:quantityType] == HKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
                [self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:nil readTypes:readDataTypes completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                    i++;
                    if (!success) {
                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"requestAuthorizationToShareTypes error: %@", error);
                        }
                        return;
                    } else {
                        if (i == [readDataTypes count]) {
                            static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
                            dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
                                [self getHeight];
                                [self getWeight];
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }];
            } else {
                if ([quantityType isEqual:[HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight]]) {
                    [self getHeight];
                } else if ([quantityType isEqual:[HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass]]) {
                    [self getWeight];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (NSSet *)dataTypesToRead
{
    HKQuantityType *height = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight];
    HKQuantityType *weight = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass];
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:height, weight, nil];
}
```

**2. Get Height and Weight:**

```
- (void)getHeight
{
    NSDateComponents *interval = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    interval.month = 1;
    HKQuantityType *quantityType = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight];

    HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query =
    [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:quantityType
                                      quantitySamplePredicate:nil
                                                      options:HKStatisticsOptionDiscreteAverage
                                                   anchorDate:[NSDate date]
                                           intervalComponents:interval];

    query.initialResultsHandler = ^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *results, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred while retrieving body mass: %@", error);
        }

        [results enumerateStatisticsFromDate:[self startDate]
                                      toDate:[NSDate date]
                                   withBlock:^(HKStatistics *result, BOOL *stop) {
                                       HKQuantity *quantity = result.averageQuantity;

                                       const int month = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
                                       static BOOL isLastMonthResult;
                                       static double lastHeight;

                                       if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:result.startDate] < month) {
                                           isLastMonthResult = YES;
                                           if (!quantity && lastHeight > 0.0) {
                                               NSLog(@"Height: %lf", lastHeight);
                                           }
                                       }

                                       if (quantity) {
                                           lastHeight = [quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit meterUnit]] * 100;
                                           if (isLastMonthResult) {
                                               NSLog(@"Height: %lf", lastHeight);
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }];
    };

    [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];
}

- (void)getWeight
{
    NSDateComponents *interval = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    interval.month = 1;
    HKQuantityType *quantityType = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass];

    HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query =
    [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:quantityType
                                      quantitySamplePredicate:nil
                                                      options:HKStatisticsOptionDiscreteAverage
                                                   anchorDate:[NSDate date]
                                           intervalComponents:interval];

    query.initialResultsHandler = ^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *results, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred while retrieving body mass: %@", error);
        }

        [results enumerateStatisticsFromDate:[self startDate]
                                      toDate:[NSDate date]
                                   withBlock:^(HKStatistics *result, BOOL *stop) {
                                       HKQuantity *quantity = result.averageQuantity;

                                       const int month = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
                                       static BOOL isLastMonthResult;
                                       static double lastWeight;

                                       if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:result.startDate] < month) {
                                           isLastMonthResult = YES;
                                           if (!quantity && lastWeight > 0.0) {
                                               NSLog(@"Weight: %lf", lastWeight);
                                           }
                                       }

                                       if (quantity) {
                                           lastWeight = [quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit gramUnit]] / 1000;
                                           if (isLastMonthResult) {
                                               NSLog(@"Weight: %lf", lastWeight);
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }];
    };

    [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];
}

- (NSDate *)startDate
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    components.hour = 0;
    components.year -= 1;
    NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    return startDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable background notification on the type of data which you want to read in background.
For example below is the method which enables background delivery on weight data. You can call this method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
-(void)enableBackgroundDeliveryForQuantityType {

    HKQuantityType *weightType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass];

    [self.healthStore enableBackgroundDeliveryForType: weightType frequency: HKUpdateFrequencyImmediate withCompletion: ^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"***** Background notification called ................. %d", success);
    }];
    HKObserverQuery *query = [[HKObserverQuery alloc] initWithSampleType: weightType predicate: nil updateHandler: ^(HKObserverQuery *query, HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler completionHandler, NSError *error) {

       if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error.... %@", error.localizedDescription);
            abort();
        }
        NSLog(@"Weight data updated");

        [self yourCustomisedMethod: completionHandler];
    }];

    [self.healthStore executeQuery: query];
}
```

On successful notification you can write your own customised method and call it.